# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entitySet when insert item using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am pass data like below. where Company name is Multi lookup Field.

```
{"Address":"","CompanyName":[{"ID":2,"Title":"InfoEngg"}],"Email":"kapil@gmail.com","Title":"Kapil","Mobileno":"9898989898","Password":"Sp@12345","EmpRole":"Level 1"}
```

Why this error throw?? how can i solve it?

Comment: Make sure you are passing value for all required column in REST API data(JSON)

Answer (score 2):

Try *changing* your `CompanyName` field to:

```
"CompanyNameId": {
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "Collection(Edm.Int32)"
    },
    "results": [ 2 ] // Array of the IDs of your selected items
}
```

Since per your comment your data format is set, why not just transform it before sending your update?

```
var data = {"Address":"","CompanyName":[{"ID":2,"Title":"InfoEngg"}],"Email":"kapil@gmail.com","Title":"Kapil","Mobileno":"9898989898","Password":"Sp@12345","EmpRole":"Level 1"};

var updateData = {
  Address: data.Address,
  CompanyNameId: {
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "Collection(Edm.Int32)"
    },
    "results": $.map(data.CompanyName, function(c) { return c.ID; })
  },
  Email: data.Email,
  Title: data.Title,
  Mobileno: data.Mobileno,
  Password: data.Password,
  EmpRole: data.EmpRole
};
```

Comment: i know this way but  i have pojo class it contains all data for that lookup

Comment: Well, you asked why you're getting an error, and that's why. The service is expecting `CompanyNameId` and it's not there. :)